# Mysql Fail to start

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I'm running a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Virtual Machine.  Last week, the VM stopped unexpectedly now mysql will not start on the VM.  These two events may be related, they may not be.

When I try to connect:

```
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Then:

```
$ sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start
```

And

$ dmesg

```
[ 1838.218400] type=1400 audit(1374633238.253:50): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=18473 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1838.358656] init: mysql main process (18477) terminated with status 1
[ 1838.358695] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[ 1839.269303] init: mysql post-start process (18478) terminated with status 1
```

And

```
$ service mysql status
mysql stop/waiting
```

I think this means mysql is crashing when it starts:

```
$ sudo mysqld start
130723 21:51:24  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 3064211200 in file fut0lst.ic line 83
InnoDB: Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
02:51:24 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
```

[Per the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/crashing.html), I went to the data directory (/var/lib/mysql) and ran this:

```
myisamchk --silent --force */*.MYI
```

Then:

```
$ sudo mysqld
...
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
...
```

Is my database corrupt?  What can I do to recover?  Re-install mysql?  Something less drastic?  I'm fine with losing the database, I just want a working system.

Comment: It seems like the innodb tables are corrupt.

Comment: It seems my database was corrupt and prevented mysql from starting.  Per the manual, I added this to /etc/mysql/my.cnf: [mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 6.  When I restarted the server, it started without crashing.

Comment: Ah okay, good to know.

Comment: My database doesn't seem to be usable yet - but at least I think I know the issue.  I'm going to re-install mysql and see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: try to delete the mysql with --purge option and than reinstall it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Recreating the mysqld.sock file might do the trick.

```
 cd /var/run/mysqld
 sudo touch mysqld.sock
 sudo chown mysql:mysql mysqld.sock
 sudo chmod 1777 mysqld.sock
 sudo service mysql restart
```

If not, please do the following and post the results:

```
 cd /var/run/mysqld
 ls -al
```

Comment: Didn't work.  "sudo service mysql restart" -- "stop: Unknown instance: start: Job failed to start".  /var/run/mysqld has "rwxrwxrwt  1 mysql mysql   0 Jul 23 22:01 mysqld.sock"

Comment: Never mind, in light of your new info above, this isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A broken MySQL install can sometimes be worked around by starting in safemode.

**Important** Running MySQL in safemode lowers the security settings, potentially allowing another person access to your data.

To start in safe mode, run:

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables
```

If you find that your tables are in fact corrupt, there are several steps that can be taken to fix them. Here is a link to a good tutorial. 
http://tech.amikelive.com/node-36/mysql-50-recovering-crashedcorrupted-innodb-database/

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/04/recovering-innodb-table-corruption/

Answer (score 0):

Check in my.cnf, look for folder `tmp` location. Then check that location's permissions to be `777`. Becuas the default permissions of folders is `755` and form `tmp` it should be `777`.

[ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run/21846112#21846112)